# What is the difference between Registers and Temporary Registers?

Tags: c, architecture, valgrind, cpu-architecture

Valgrind uses an intermediate code representation to let us instrument binary code so that we don't have to deal with programming language level constructs. In the process of converting binary code into Valgrind's Intermediate Representation (IR) code, it shows the use of registers for operations like additions etc. There are 1024 of these that are being used. What I don't get is another type of registers called temporary registers represented as `tX` where X is some number. Thus, I can see this:

```
t28 = Add32(t26,0xFFFFFFFC:I32)
t4 = LDle:I32(t28)
```

`t` meaning a temporary register. As far as I can see, they seem to behave very similar to regular registers but am not able to figure out how they are different. Can someone tell me what a temporary register is and how it differs from a regular register?

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I see neither `R` nor `T` in that example...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In compiler construction class I was taught that registers in intermediate code are virtual registers. They don't necessarily have anything to do with the executable for the target platform. They could be real CPU registers, or they can be temporaries in memory. It all depends on the code generator and the optimizer. It is the code generator that decides where the temporaries should be allocated.

A big reason for generating IR is to maximize the portability of the compiler. You can use one compiler front end for all platforms, and then pass the IR to platform specific code generators. GCC works this way, and I'm sure most, if not all, decent compilers work this way.

Another benefit is that you can perform certain optimizations on the IR code, before it is sent to the code generator. Some optimizations are not platform specific: for instance, code that aren't affected by a loop, can be pulled out of the loop. The platform optimizer typically optimizes on a lower level such as register allocation, branching, etc, stuff that really depends on the properties of the CPU.